# Writing each column of a matrix into different text files in R

Tags: r, matrix, text

I have following matrix, and I would like to write rownames and multiple columns into a text file by only taking column by column. Is there a way of doing so?

```
r1 <- c("0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","1","0","0")
r2 <- c("1","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","1","0","1","0","0")
r3 <- c("0","1","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","0","1","0")
r4 <- c("0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0","0","1")
r5 <- c("0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","0","1")

n.mat <- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
```

So in the end I would like to have 13 textiles each containing a rowname column and one column containing the `0` and `1`.

```
Textfile 1      Textfile 2       ................
   V1                V2
r1 0             r1  0
r2 1             r2  0
r3 0             r3  1
r4 0             r4  0
r5 0             r5  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and use e.g. `cat` to write it out.

```
for(i in seq_len(ncol(n.mat))) {cat(n.mat[,i], file=paste0("Textfile", i))}
```

and with a header and in column:

```
for(i in seq_len(ncol(n.mat))) {cat(c(paste0("V",i), n.mat[,i]),
 file=paste0("Textfile", i), sep="\n")}
```

And with rownames (but better use `write.table` - only to show how it could be done):

```
for(i in seq_len(ncol(n.mat))) {cat(c(paste0("   V",i),
 paste(row.names(n.mat), n.mat[,i])), file=paste0("Textfile", i), sep="\n")}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a for loop, something like:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(n.mat)) {
  write.table(x = n.mat[, i, drop = FALSE], file = paste0("n.mat.column", i, ".txt"))
}
```

Comment: Hi, I get the error:
'Warning in if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument'

Comment: Oops, got my arguments in the wrong order. Editing now.